# Polygon union with arcs

Tags: algorithms, graphics

I have two non-convex polygon which intersect one another. I have written program years ago to find union polygons. I described that I has been used algorithm Weiler-Atherton. But in Wikipedia I found that Weiler–Atherton algorithm is for clipping - is Weiler-Atherton for polygon union or I have mistaken the name?
This program uses also Bentley–Ottmann algorithm for find crossing segments.
Now I want extend possibilities to compute union of special polygon, which segments can be arcs with chord and sagitta.
How to extend this algorithm? Union algorithms choose always most right or most left segment on cross, here arcs can be ambiguous unless sagitta is small, and if not - this arcs can be divided.